# Validate record via Javascript

Tags: javascript

We are checking the couple of conditions based on javascript logic.

1. Contact email checking: if the contact email is already associated with some other user we needs to be popup message like:

   > "User is already exists with the same email".
2. Partner Licence checking: if there is no licences then we need to popup message like "You have not enough license available,please create support case".

I have tried below Javascript logic, the above points are not working.

Button Logic:

var results = sforce.apex.execute("validatePartnar", "validatePartnerId",{contactId:"{!Contact.Id}"},{contactEmail:"{!Contact.Email}"},{});

---

Web service class:

lobal class validatePartnar{
    webService static string validatePartnerId(String contactId,String contactEmail){
        string message ='';
        List conListForPartnar = [SELECT Id,AccountId,Account.IsPartner,Partner_User__c,Partner_Type__c from Contact where id =: contactId LIMIT 1];
        List conListForEmail = [SELECT Id,name, email from user where email =:contactEmail];

```
    if(conListForEmail.size() > 0){ 
        message = 'User is already exists with the same email'; 
        return message;
    } 

    else{
    return message;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: You need to set the __sfdcSessionId 
<script type="text/javascript">
var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
2
AJAX Toolkit Developer Guide AJAX Toolkit Support Policy
</script>
<script src="../../soap/ajax/40.0/connection.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> see this https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/apex_ajax.pdf

Comment: Why did you deface your question and remove the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the declaration of the variable ***userlicns***. There is another way to validate code if you write a web service & consume it from a button

// web service to validate.

```
global class validatePartnar{
    webService static string validatePartnerId(String contactId,String contactEmail){
        String message ='';
        List<Contact> conListForPartnar = [SELECT Id,AccountId,Account.IsPartner,Partner_User__c,Partner_Type__c from Contact where id =: contactId LIMIT 1];
        List<Contact> conListForEmail = [SELECT Id,name, email from user where email =:contactEmail limit 1];

        if(conListForPartnar <> NULL && conListForPartnar.size() > 0 && conListForPartnar[0].Partner_User__c == 'false'){ 
            message = 'This contact is associated to an account that is not partner enabled. Please mention SFDC Support to open a case.'; 
            return message;
        }
        else{
            System.debug('******** Partner_User__c validation passeed ***********');
        }
        if(conListForEmail <> NULL && conListForEmail.size() > 0){ 
            message = 'User is already exists with the same email'; 
            return message;
        } 
        else{
            System.debug('******** Email validation passeed ***********');
        }
        return message;
    }

}
```

==============   button code =================

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/39.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/39.0/apex.js")} 

    var result = sforce.apex.execute("validatePartnar", "validatePartnerId",{contactId:"{!Contact.Id}",contactEmail:"{!Contact.Email}"}); 
    alert(result);
```

Hope this will resolve the issue as well as check userlicns variable I don't see any issue with this code apart from that variable.Please note salesforce favor to use lightning component instead. See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/09/why-its-time-to-break-up-with-javascript-buttons-and-embrace-lightning.html)

Comment: @Avijith, Can you please suggest me if am not wrong where i can use the above _SfdcSessionID.Should i create a new VF page or can i use same lines on my top of the javascript code.Please help us for this.  Thanks

Comment: At the top before using sforce commands

Comment: @Avijith, Don't mind can you please edit my logic with _SfdcSessionID. i have tried not getting proper popup messages.Please help me for this. Thanks

Comment: @Ram Are you trying to do this in classic correct? And your queries returning values? did you tried to put alerts after the statement
alert(records ); 
alert(userrecd);
alert(records[0].Partner_User__c);

Comment: @Avijith,Yes, i have used alerts for userecrd and licences there is no proper outcome which i have expecting.Please help me for this for me it is very high priority.

Comment: @Avijith,I have created new we service class and i have used the variable on my button logic as you mentioned above, but am getting  below error like "On Success not defined in the call back".please help me on this Thanks

Comment: @Ram: I updated the syntax to call the method please update any try there was a syntax error

Comment: @Avijith,Please see my edited and updated logic which we have tried.still getting same error.Thanks

Comment: please set this after required script 
sforce.debug.trace=true;
it will help us to debug On Success not defined in the call back should not come

Comment: @Avijith ,After adding sforce.debug.trace=true; working as expected.But getting errors "Ajax Toolkit Shell Errors".The window pops up anytime like "Features: autocompletion of property names with Tab, multiline input with Shift+Enter, input history with Up/Down
Values and functions: ans, print(string), props(object), blink(node), clear(), load(scriptURL), scope(object)" .Why am getting this every time and how to avoid them.Please help us. Thanks